# How to fetch single record from SQLite in flutter and store in model class for use

Tags: flutter, addition, sqflite

I am not good in flutter but learning it . I am working with SQLite and want to fetch single record and want to map it to model class then want to show it in text widget.

Need help and thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Your SQL will look like `SELECT columns, you, want FROM sometable WHERE somecondition;` and then you'll gt back a list of values from the selected columns.  It's up to you to map those values into an object constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future<User> fetchUser(String email) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final map = await db.rawQuery(
      "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE email = ?",[email]
    );

    if (map.isNotEmpty) {
      return User.fromJson(map.first);
    } else {
      throw Exception("User: $email not found");
    }
  }
```

To use it in a Text widget:

```
  //Create a variable of your model class
  User? user;
  
  //call this method in init to fetch user by email
  void getUser()async{
    
    //call your Database fetch method
    user = await database.instance.fetchUser("a@.com");
  }
  
  //Use it like this in a Text Widget
  Text("${user.email}" ?? "NA"),
```

Comment: and how to display in text widget

Comment: one more thing i want to ask kindly add depedend dropodwn based on country and city from sqlite with the help of model class. i can not post another question because stackoverflow block me posting questions so kindly add it in the answer please

Comment: you mean fetch by using country and city?

Comment: i want to show country in dropdown when i select india it will show states in another dropdown. i want to create also dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import 'package:path/path.dart';
  import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
  import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';




  Database? _db;
   static const createNotesTable = ''' 
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "notes" (
   "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
   "userid" INTEGER NOT NULL,
   "text"   TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
   );''';
  const dbName = 'notes.db';
  const noteTable = 'note';
  ///Create Table
  Future<void>open()
   {
     final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
     final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
     final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
     _db = db;

     await db.execute(createNotesTable);

   }

  ///  get data using id 
  ///  DataBaseNotes is My Notes Model Class
  Future<DataBaseNotes> getNote({required int id}) async
   {

      final notes = await db.query(
      noteTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id= ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
      );
    return note;

   }
```

Comment: now how to display on text widget?

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Refer this db service dart file, [(https://gist.github.com/Madhan-Rkv-10/2be709df769229a919fe21cf534358ce), then You can implement in UI.